# Как на C# проверить, запущена ли служба "Х" или нет, и узнать тип запуска(авто) и изменить параметры-выкл,включить, поставить в автозапуск?

Tags: c#, windows-service

Как на C#  проверить, запущена ли служба Windows "Х" или нет, и узнать тип запуска(авто) и изменить параметры-выкл,включить, поставить в автозапуск?

Comment: Могу список API указать...

Comment: @"Владимир Мартьянов " ну напишите пример

Answer (score 5):

Есть класс [ServiceController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx). Я думаю, что его функционала будет достаточно и не нужно лезть в WinApi.

**UPD:**

Единственное, чего не хватает в ServiceController, как я понял - это смены типа запуска.

В этом случае можно вспользоваться методами [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477618/how-do-i-change-a-windows-services-startup-type-in-net-post-install).

Предлагается:

1. Обратится к WinApi
2. Обратится к WMI
3. Обратится к CMD

Еще нашел вариант через реестр:

```
   using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

public enum ServiceStart
{
Boot = 0,
System = 1,
Automatic = 2,
Manual = 3,
Disabled = 4
}

public class ServiceController2 : System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController
{

public ServiceStart ServiceStart
{
 get
 {
    RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
     "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\" + this.ServiceName );
      ServiceStart start = (ServiceStart)key.GetValue("Start");
     key.Close(); 
     return (start);
 }

 set
 {
       RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
         "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\" + this.ServiceName, true );
       key.SetValue( "Start", (int)value );
       key.Close();
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: WMI в PowerShell хорошо, в C# не очень

Answer (score 3):

Список WinAPI:

`OpenSCManager()` + `OpenService()` - открытие конкретного сервиса по имени. Заодно проверка на наличие такого сервиса в принципе. Потом:
`QueryServiceStatusEx()` - текущее состояние сервиса
`QueryServiceConfig()` - тип запуска
`ChangeServiceConfig()` - изменение параметров, включая тип запуска
`ControlService()` - приостановка или остановка сервиса.